# Page in Facebook App doesn't load

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, swift3

I'm having some problems opening a page in Facebook App. The Facebook application opens, however the page is not displayed, it simply doesn't load.

I don't have problems opening it in Safari, the problem is with Facebook app.

I added everything to LSApplicationQueriesSchemes: fb, fbapi, fb-messenger-api, fbauth2, fbshareextension.

Here is my code:

```
    func tapFacebook(){

    let appURL = NSURL(string: "fb://page/xxxxx")!
    let webURL = NSURL(string: "https://www.facebook.com/xxxxx/")!
    let application = UIApplication.shared

    if application.canOpenURL(appURL as URL) {

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            application.open(appURL as URL)
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
    } else {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            application.open(webURL as URL)
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
    }

    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to open ? Any error messages in console ? Have you tried using `fb://page/?id=SOME_ID` ?

Comment: xxxxx is the page's ID, no error. The page loads fine in Safari, but not in Facebook App.

Comment: Try using `fb://page/?id=xxxxx` as the scheme instead. And there's no need for `NSUR`L, change it to `URL` if you can.

Comment: Thanks @nathan but, I made the changes but it still does not work.

Comment: @Xenetrix Did you add access to open for Facebook app?

Comment: Hi guys I've found the solution. Facebook has changed page schema. Now they use the profile schema for pages in iOS app, "fb://page/xxxxx" is replaced by "fb://profile/xxxxx"